# Remove a view from SuperView using a flag in MvvmCross Binding Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

We need to remove a view from superview in Xamarin.iOS using MvvmCross Binding based on one flag. We are able to hide the view using a flag. As Hidden is property for the view and RemoveFromSuperView() is a method.

Below is the code we are doing for hiding the view

```
var set = this.CreateBindingSet<MeetingEventCard, Meeting>();
set.Bind(MeetingView).For(v => v.Hidden).To("IsTypeMeeting == false");
set.Apply();
```

Thanks,
Ram

Comment: If you remove a superview don't you think you will have reset the constraints for every view in the hierarchy

Comment: @FreakyAli, Thanks for looking into it. I have added constraints with low priority.